# trigger sheet need to be executed when change occurred in particular sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to give last cell value of col no. 20 when mail has been sent with time and date in the below script. and using this code when more than one rows are added at a time then "sent" value is being added to the last row only and remaining rows are left blank. when new other row is added since value is not equal to sent those values are also been attached So, when mail sent complete column need to be given value as sent. Once please check this

```
function sendEmail() {

     //setup function
     var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
     var StartRow = 2;
     var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
     var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,16);
     var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
    
     var message = "";
     //iterate loop
     for (i in AllValues) {
    
         //set current row
         var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
        
         //define column to check if sent (starts from "0" not "1")
         var EmailSent = CurrentRow[14];
         var caseworker = CurrentRow[7];
        
         //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
         if (EmailSent == "sent") 
             continue;
        
         //set HTML template for information
          message +=
              "<p><b>Bank: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Branch: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Region: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Lan Number: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Customer Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Loan Type: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Case Worker: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Site Visit Status: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Site Visit Done By: </b>" + CurrentRow[9] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Document recieved: </b>" + CurrentRow[11] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>File Upload: </b>" + CurrentRow[12] + "</p>" +
              "<p><b>Remarks: </b>" + CurrentRow[10] + "</p><br><br>";
        
          //set the row to look at
          var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;
        
          //mark row as "sent"
          ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 15).setValue("sent");
    }
    //define who to send grants to
    var SendTo = "#######@gmail.com" + "," + "#########@gmail.com" + "," + "    #########@gmail.com";
     
      
     //set subject line
     var Subject = "New case initiated to Shirisha";
    
    
      //send the actual email  
       MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: SendTo,
          cc: "#########@gmail.com",
          subject: Subject,
          htmlBody: message,
    });
}
```

Comment: onChange() changeType "OTHER" will fire on imports but the event object doesn't have a lot of information [onChange event  object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)  look at the actual event object with Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

Comment: It is very much to me. Can you please modify it. I am very new to the coding.

Comment: As suggested in another question, please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts regarding Google Apps Script triggers in Google Sheets.

Comment: @Rubén Can you set value for column no 16 as sent mail date and time

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what is being asked.

Comment: Please clarify how are the rows added to your sheet, and which trigger do you use. Another confuion is the no of column (in code = 15, in question = 20, in discussion = 16)

Comment: @MikeSteelson I am pulling rows from another spreadsheet using Query function with a condition in sheets. I have used onChange trigger. When new row is added it will immediately trigger and send the mail. I need when new row is added and triggered mail. I need to give value to the last column as sent and next column as time stamp.

Comment: what you need is impossible to do. If the rows are imported by query, they depend on the source. If you modify the source, sort it, delete rows, the result will be affected, i.e. you will have put 'sent' and date in other columns, this information will be assigned to other elements than previously.